# How to check for [ ] at beginning and end of string

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I check for `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end of a string using a regular expression?

I am trying to check if the string can be used by `JSON.parse`.

`/\A[\w\z]/` is what I came up with, but doesn't seem like it's working.

Comment: You may use `/\A\[.*\]\z/m` to check if any string starts with `[` and ends with `]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you this works! please add an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: If your real purpose is to check for correct JSON format, then this is an XY-problem. You should actually parse it as JSON, wrapped in a rescue block, and see if it detects any JSON parsing errors.

Comment: Was just about to suggest what @sawa said. Example code: `begin; JSON.parse(my_string); rescue JSON::ParserError; false; else; true; end`. Or if you prefer short and cryptic: `JSON.parse(my_string) && true rescue false` Though in your real use case, perhaps instead of returning a boolean you want to Do Something Useful with the parsed JSON.

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex? Because?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for a regex, use `start_with` and `end_with`:

```
s = "[text\nhere]"
puts s.start_with?("[") and s.end_with?("]")
# => true
```

See [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/7dlTkR)

If you need a regex, you may use

```
/\A\[.*\]\z/m
```

to check if any string starts with `[` and ends with `]`.

**Explanation**:

- `\A` - start of a string
- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `.*` - 0+ any characters, even incl. a newline due to the `/m` modifier)
- `\]` - a closing `]`
- `\z` - the very end of the string.

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/jxG9lP9sTp)

Comment: Note that your `\A[\w\z]` pattern matches the start of a string, and then 1 character: either a word char (letter/digit/_) or a `z` (since the `\z` is disambiguated as `z` as this `\z` is not treated as an anchor inside a character class).

Comment: The regex should only contain 2 regex delimiters, so it should be `if self.text =~ /\A\[.*\]\z/m { }`

Comment: Use the methods over the regular expression. The methods are faster and more clearly show what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to check at beginning and end, why not

```
string = "[foo..bar]"
str = string.strip
str[0] == "[" && str[-1] == "]"
```

Answer (score -2):

Since the square brackets `[]` are used to create a regular expression list, you must escape them:

```
 /\A\[.*\]\z/
```

Comment: Thanks! the `\w` will take any number of characters in between the `[ ]` right?

Comment: I had thought you were sure of what you wanted in there.. I've modified it to look for strings that start and end with square brackets regardless of what lies between.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer The `\z` (for end-of-string) needs to go after the ending bracket, and `.` won't match newlines without a `/m` flag as in Wiktor's answer.

Comment: Actually, `/\A\[.*\z\]/` is an example of a regex that will never match :)

Comment: Right you are.  Sorry, it's been a super long day. :)